# Pushing and tagging cloned repositories into my git server

Tags: git, github, git-clone

One of our current applications relies on a cloned read-only library from github (let's call it XXLib).  When I cut and release a build of my application, I tag it as a specific version (say, v1.1), however, given that XXLib can and will change over time, how can I tag the specific version of XXLib into my central repository so that I can always go back and re-build?

One thought I had is to create a new repository on my central git server, add a tracking branch for XXLib in my workspace that allows me to push the contents of my workspace to our central server at the time I do the build. ie. XXLib in my workspace has two remotes (origin and mygitserver) that I use to pull (origin) and push (mygitserver)

Or is this a case for submodules?

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: Local repo with two remotes (github and mygitserver) will do. And you don't need to worry about pushing local tags/changes to github since it's read-only).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Import the remote library as a submodule. If you need to make your own changes to it, put them in your own Git repository that pulls from the GitHub repository.

```
XXLib-GitHub
  |
XXLib-Your-Fork
  |
Your-app
```

Comment: You know, I never got around to accepting your answer and here we are a year later.  My humble apologies...